# React derived Component doesn't update on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am new to react and this is more kind of a conceptual question rather than specific programming.

I have a main component which have 3 sub components. Call them `A, B, C`. A is a graph, B is an Image and C is a set of radio buttons(X,Y,Z). There is a state related to C which has default `{buttonSelected: "Y"}`.

When the main component loads, a function `prepareData(this.state.buttonSelected)` is called from `render()`. This function will prepare all the data required to show in graph and the Image, and then populates the data on an object and returns the object. All the graph and image inside `return()` of main component is created using this returned object and the component loads successfully.

Now when I click on radiobutton `X` again `prepareData(this.state.buttonSelected)` is called with correct `X` value from `render()` it will also return object populated with correct data for graph and image. But the graph and image doesn't re-render with new values.

Is this because the data to create graph and image aren't in state ? Does every part that needs to re-render should be associated with `props or state` and the data derived from another state are not re-rendered ?

edit: added pseudocode

```
const prepareData = buttonSelected => {
   <chart data and image preparation based on buttonSelected >
   object.chartdata, object.imagedata = <prepared data>
   return object
}

class MainComponent extends Component {
   constructor(){
      this.state = {buttonSelected: "Y"}
   }

onButtonClick(c){ 
   this.setState({buttonSelected: c})
}
render(){ 
   returnData = prepareData(this.state.buttonSelected)
   return (
   <JSX using retrunData>
   <...... onClick ={() => this.onButtonClick("Y") >
   <Chart data = {returnData.chartdata} />
   <Image source={returnData.imagedata} />

}
```

Comment: Can you share your prepareData function? even if its just pseudocode

Comment: @sme I have added pseudocode. Please check.

Comment: are Image and Graph components extended from `PureComponent`? Do they introduce any logic in their `shouldComponentUpdate()`?

Comment: Yes they are pure and the graph is react-chartjs2 image is just an image and the source comes from prepareData. There is no shouldComponentUpdate implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is  correct.

Render is triggered when component state is changed. The state can change from a props change or from a direct setState change. After that react based on updated state decides whether to re-render.

In your case props and state are not changing after prepareData invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So here I need to put the image source and chart data inside the state and call setState to change the data rather than returning object and using it to prepare data ? For that I need to bring `prepareData()` function inside the class itself. Am I correct ?

Comment: But the props for the chart and image are changing after I call `prepareData`. Can you check two lines added at last in the above pseudocode. This still doesn't update component.

Comment: Move "returnData = prepareData(this.state.buttonSelected)"  out of render and place it under onButtonClick afterwards  this.setState({returnData }) and from render access it e.g. this.state.returnData.chartdata